# How to validate a radio button in a form Angular 5

Tags: validation, angular5, radio-group

I have the following `form` where I want to `validate` the `mat-radio-group` as well, but since it does not support `formControl` I don't know how can I achieve that?

Anyone knows?

Here is my **`HTML`**

```
<h2 class="mat-title" style="text-align:center;">Register as a {{person}}</h2>
<form class="example-form" [formGroup]="registerForm" (submit)="onSubmit(registerForm)" novalidate>
  <div class="example-selected-valuec mat-subheading-2">Your gender is: {{gender}}</div>
  <mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]="gender" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let gender of genders" [value]="gender">
      {{gender}}
    </mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
  <br>
  <!--<div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.gender.invalid && (registerForm.controls.gender.dirty || registerForm.controls.gender.touched)"
    class="alert alert-danger">
    <div class="error mat-body-2" *ngIf="registerForm.controls.gender.errors.required">
      You must fill out your gender
    </div>
  </div>-->
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input id="username" formControlName="username" matInput placeholder="Username">
  </mat-form-field>
  <div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.username.invalid && (registerForm.controls.username.dirty || registerForm.controls.username.touched)"
    class="alert alert-danger">
    <div class="error mat-body-2" *ngIf="registerForm.controls.username.errors.required">
      You must fill out your username
    </div>
    <div class="error mat-body-2" *ngIf="registerForm.controls.username.errors.email && !registerForm.controls.username.errors.required">
      Invalid email address
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="register" mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="registerForm.invalid">Register</button>
</form>
```

Comment: i have the same problem

Comment: https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-required-validation-example